# How to speed up `docker load` then `docker pull` the incremental changes

Tags: docker, docker-image

My docker develop site and private registry located on site A. The production site B is connecting by 1 MB bandwidth network.

I have build a large image about 14GB and put it on private docker registry:2.

Because transfer 14GB by 'docker pull' always hang for small network bandwidth. I use `docker save` then compressed as xz file and transfer to production site. The tar.xz file is about 800MB and suitable for first setup on production site.

Now, I just append one line RUN script on Dockerfile to change the image and push to registry in 1 second.  I wish it could pull the samll change on production site for only a few seconds. But, The `docker pull` command always trying to pull an old large layer about 1.4 GB.

I'm wonder why it is not cached by the first time 'docker load'?  Is there any method to improve pull speed.

```
$ docker pull 192.168.1.2:5000/large
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from large
cbddbc0189a0: Already exists
d79d36371fdd: Already exists
22a28ad6d786: Already exists
8d977d3c35c4: Already exists
82bf6088772f: Already exists
c3721275c963: Already exists
e6094577f1ab: Already exists
fae943dde872: Already exists
a750c973438c: Already exists
eaa46ee01cde: Already exists
c6a587da73bc: Downloading [>      ]  1.596MB/1.393GB
1a237f393bcc: Download complete
2f9ea1299990: Download complete
084da7095dce: Download complete
56dc8872f673: Download complete
b564807882b8: Download complete
c6763845a161: Download complete
ab30373e73e1: Download complete
d215b08dc34e: Download complete
b4969cff1817: Download complete
56d6d67ceed8: Downloading [===>         ]  463.2kB/7.016MB
eec215ecbaa9: Download complete
5bd3119d46dd: Download complete
dde99cd229a7: Download complete
a9625b7300e1: Download complete
b9bb74922ed7: Download complete
23d0d72df613: Download complete
85bf8e03320b: Download complete
00120183b69f: Download complete
```